# MVC 4 javascript not rendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, rendering

I cant seem to get these (js files) rendered.

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      @if (IsSectionDefined("scripts"))
    {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: true)
    }

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@section scripts

{   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/firebugx.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/jquery.jsonp-1.1.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/slick.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/slick.formatters.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/slick.editors.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/slick.grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/slick.dataview.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/WarehouseJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error occur? The page itself should load. And there's a problem with this line:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And make sure that your WarehouseJavaScript.js is NOT in the scripts folder, otherwise you have to edit this line:

```
<script src="/WarehouseJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The error occurs for all the references (chrome debugger console). The control never really goes to the references.
I have commented the problem line. WarehouseJavaScript.js is not in the Scripts folder.